# Talend Studio - Search inside Metadata to get all the queries created

Tags: metadata, talend, database-metadata

I'm using Talend Studio,

I've a lot of jobs created each one with multiple queries.

I want to to search for all the jobs that have the SQL Statement "Insert Into".

There exists any place (like a database) where Talend save the commands and we can list all of them?

For example, SQL Server Reporting Services have the Report Server Database where I can find all the reports with a specific query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any such database within Talend, but you can look in the directory

```
<workspace>/<projectName>/process
```

and there will be an XML file for each job called `<jobname>_<version>.item` which contains all the settings for the job and each of the components.

A simple text search will find what you are looking for if you are looking for components configured with an "INSERT INTO" statement. You could use XSL or XQUERY with these files if you want to be a bit more sophisticated.

However, if you are looking for components that have an "INSERT INTO" command as a result of the code generation, then you probably need to search the generated code, which will be a bit more complicated, especially since you would have to see what sort of code each individual component compiled.

In 7.0.1 the generated code is found in

```
<workspace>/<projectName>/poms/jobs/process/<jobname>_<version>/src/main/java/<projectNameInLowerCase>
```